# What is a good DRF Serializer design for flexibility

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've read a lot of similar topics and I know there are a number of ways that would accomplish the goal, but I'm wondering if anybody has an opinion on this one.

**Problem Statement**

My application has two primarily types of users. Customers and Staff members. When retrieving data from an endpoint, it is not uncommon for customers to see viewer fields than staff.

In addition, data from a list view generally has fewer fields than that of a retrieve.

**Solution?**

Create a serializer for each method, as well for each user type. For example, in an /orders endpoint I may have up to 8 different serializers

OrdersListStaffSerializer

OrdersListCustSerializer

OrdersRetrieveStaffSerializer.... etc

Then I can simply choose the proper serializer for the condition.

**PROS**

Seems like good flexibility in being able to control exactly who can see what, and also what data they are allowed to write.

**CONS**

Feels like there could be a lot of duplication of effort.

Lacks the ability to have a finer grain control of data based on permissions.

Wondering if anybody has had any experience following this type of design and if it has worked well or become too cumbersome to maintain.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not implement a `BaseSerializer` that handles common problems, and then subclass it into individual serializers (like `OrdersListStaffSerializer`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a very raw solution but if you find yourself wanting a finer grained way of showing fields based on the user's permission, then you could try it out.

First, make all the fields that need permission `SerializerMethodField`.
In each method, check user permissions and return the field value if he has access, else, return a placeholder like `_Not_Permitted_`

Lastly, In the serializer's `to_representation` method, remove all fields with the placeholder value `_Not_Permitted_` that you defined ealier.

Like I said, this is a very raw solution but it gives you total control over what each user sees to down to the field level

**BTW**, you could also just go ahead and check the permissions in the `to_representation` method and not use `SerializerMethodField`s